# Need TFS Build that copies documentation files to network share on check-in (but there is no sln to build) - like VSS shadow

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

First, here's some background & what I am trying to achieve in general:

Under the main trunk for my application in TFS, there is folder tree containing numerous documents (Word files etc) - user manuals, technical specifications etc. As releases are made, the entire trunk is branched (so the state of both the application and the documentation is captured when the release is made). The documentation folder tree is deliberately OUTSIDE the various folders containing the VS solutions; the files are updated by various people who don't necessarily have Visual Studio. It looks like this:

- Main

  - Core
  - Documentation
  - UI
  - Reports
- Releases

  - 1.0.0

    - Core
    - Documentation
    - UI
    - Reports
  - 1.1.0

    - Core
    - Documentation
    - UI
    - Reports

Every time a file under any Documentation folder is checked in, I want that file to be copied to an equivalent folder on a file share. When a release branch is made, I would also like the entire Documentation folder to be copied to the equivalent folder on the file share. For example:

- Main

  - Documentation        ---------> \doc-server\docs\main
- Releases

  - 1.0.0

    - Documentation     ---------> \doc-server\docs\1.0.0
  - 1.1.0

    - Documentation     ---------> \doc-server\docs\1.1.0

This deployment has to be done by the TFS server, and triggered by check-ins/branching - when the documents are edited, they are not inside any VS solution, so there is no build.

Everything I have read about TFS Build indicates there must be a solution that gets built to trigger a deployment. What I am looking for is something like the "shadow" feature of VSS, where the server would automatically copy selected project folders to the file system.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dummy SOLUTION to get by the build definition where it asks for the SOLUTION to build part. You can create a dummy/blank solution file like this New Project -> Other Project Type -> Visual Studio Solution -> Blank Solution. Use that SLN file within the build defintion.

Then edit your default build template and add the CopyDirectory and InvokeProcess activity to do the additional copy work (to the share) that you want to do. If you want to copy an entire directory you can use the CopyDirectory activity or if you want to copy specific file extensions etc you can use the InvokeProcess activity.

CopyDirectory is straight forward, you just add the source and destination location and you are good to go. For InvokeProcess you can enter the "FileName = xcopy.exe" and fill in the correct arguments.

Triggering this build definition during check-in is easy (Go to the Trigger tab in the build definition and select "Continous Integration - Build each Check in"). But I am not sure how to trigger a build when branching happens.

This is very straight forward, let me know if you need help.

Comment: What's in Build.csproj? What kind of project should he use? How should he set up the build actions?

Comment: Ignore the build.csproj. You can create a dummy/blank solution file like this New Project -> Other Project Type -> Visual Studio Solution -> Blank Solution. Use that SLN file within the build defintion.

Comment: Ok, so can you elaborate on the two added activities?

Comment: Thanks, but you could still do better. I've done build process customizations, but many people have not. Perhaps you could provide some links, if not the details

Comment: Thanks Isaiah - I got it to work. Its triggered on checkin (not sure what to do about the branches but I'll leave that for now).